# Difference between dimensions and matrices in google analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am new to google analytics and have started to learn how to form a query on a profile, I was not getting the difference between dimensions and matrices in the Query.

Also, how do we concatenate 2 different queries in google analytics ?

I had successfully run the HelloAnalytics.java code with my google analytics account, then I modified the code to fetch real time data. I now wanted to apply more constraints on the data, but was not able to use AND to concatenate 2 stories. My code snippet is -

```
Analytics.Data.Realtime.Get realtimeRequest = analytics.data().realtime()
                .get("ga:" + profileId,
                        ""rt:eventLabel == CLICK_APP AND rt:activeUsers"")
                .setDimensions("rt:medium");
```

It is giving output as

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Invalid dimension or metric: rt:eventLabel == CLICK_APP AND rt:activeUsers",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid dimension or metric: rt:eventLabel == CLICK_APP AND rt:activeUsers"
}
```

Comment: Read this documentation for Real Time reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get

Comment: You need to pass in valid metrics comma separated. you have passed in a random string "rt:evenLabel == CLICK_APP AND rt:activeUsers"